# Taylor Series Exercise

Tags: taylor-expansion

What method should I use to find the Taylor series of $f(x)=\frac{x+2}{2-3x}$ with center 2?
Here's what I did:

---

Let $y=x-2$

$f(x)=-\frac{y+5}{3y+4}=-(\frac{y}{3y+4}+\frac{4}{3y+4})=-(\frac{1}{4}\frac{y}{1-(-\frac{3}{4}y)}+\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{3}{4}y)})=-(\frac{1}{4}\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{3}{4})^ny^n+\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-\frac{3}{4})^ny^n)$

---

Is my thought right? How should I continue from here if it is right.

Comment: Whichever one you feel most comfortable with? What goes wrong when you try to apply what you know?

Comment: Ok I edit my question of what I did so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=\frac{x+2}{2-3x} = \frac{1}{3} \, \frac{6 + 3x}{2-3x} = \frac{1}{3} \, \frac{8 - (2-3x)}{2-3x} = \frac{1}{3} \, \left( \frac{8}{2-3x} - 1 \right) = \frac{4}{3} \, \frac{1}{1 - \frac{3 \, x}{2}} - \frac{1}{3} $ 
Now find the Taylor series for $\frac{1}{1 - \frac{3x}{2}}$ in the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \, \frac{(x-2)^{n}}{n!}$.

Let $a=3/2$. The derivatives of $(1-ax)^{-1}$ yield
$$D^{m} (1-ax)^{-1} = m! \, a^{m} \, (1-ax)^{-m-1}$$
for which 
$$a_{n} = \left. D^{n} (1-ax)^{-1} \right|_{x=2} = n! \, a^{n} \, (1-2a)^{-n-1} = n! \, \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n} \, (1-3)^{-n-1} = - \frac{n!}{2} \, \left(- \frac{3}{4}\right)^{n}$$

This leads to:
\begin{align}
f(x) &= - \frac{1}{3} - \frac{2}{3} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(- \frac{3}{4} \right)^{n} \, (x-2)^{n} = -1 - \frac{2}{3} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 
\left(- \frac{3}{4} \right)^{n} \, (x-2)^{n}.
\end{align}